# Can the Mocha client run tests written for Cucumber / Gherkin?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, mocha.js, integration, gherkin

We have a large test-suite based on [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) ([BDD](https://mochajs.org/#bdd)), and run by the Mocha [command-line client](https://mochajs.org/#usage). Some of our designers / product managers would like to contribute test scenarios written in the [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin) language (plus [World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md) / [Step](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md) definitions and [Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md) in JavaScript).

If we want to integrate those new test scenarios into our existing Mocha test-tree, what would be the recommended way to do this without sacrificing any basic [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) functionality? (Ideally, those same tests should also still be runnable with the [Cucumber client](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md).)

I don't yet understand Cucumber / Gherkin well enough to answer this myself, though I suspect it shouldn't be too difficult. Both Mocha and Cucumber seem to be quite modular, and I've seen one or two [plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-gherkin) that look promising. But I can't quite see how the pieces fit together.

---

For example, I imagine something like this should be possible with the right setup:

```
import gherkinToMocha from 'gherkin-to-mocha'

describe('test-tree', () => {
    describe('Mocha test', () => {
        it('can run', () => {})
    })
    describe('Cucumber / Gherkin tests', () => {
        return gherkinToMocha('./test-scenario.feature')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way I see of quickly allowing product and design people to define feature files and then integrating the scenarios with your current test suite would probably be using the [mocha-gherkin](https://github.com/mklabs/mocha-gherkin) tool you mentioned.

You could make a folder available in your repository where product and design people are free to push feature files. Then you can have a script to generate "step-definition" files for all feature files in that folder, based on mocha-gherkin's usage:

```
cat file.feature | mocha-gherkin > test.js
```

I'd still make sure before the feature files are merged, they are properly reviewed by engineers so that steps that are similar are made uniform throughout the feature files, and the scenarios are valid.